# Vuetify with 3rd party form component - how to style like v-text-field

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify components as much as possible however there is no date AND time picker control so I'm using this one:
https://github.com/mariomka/vue-datetime

However when it's on the form it looks substantially different than the regular vuetify components such as v-text-field which have a style for focus and input that changes to underline etc.

My question is, what is the appropriate technique or best practice to make 3rd party components visually similar to the vuetify built in ones?

Comment: Maybe https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuetify-scss

Comment: You could create your own Datetimepicker with out of Vuetify elements; or checkout the one's already made by the community, like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuetify-datetime-picker

Comment: @ehmprah that picker is not going to work unfortunately, it doesn't support validation and assumes a certain icon set is being used.  Where is a good place to find other community ones you mentioned?